# Is it good or bad to share big json data in Angular components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular, components

Considering the code below, is it good to share a big json data as an input to test component or make use of service.

```
vm.data = [{name: 'John'},{name: 'Steve'},...];

<test-component big-data="{{vm.data}}"></test-component>
```

Which would be the ideal approach using Angular 1.5 and as well as Angular-2 components?

Comment: if you want to use big data in test component its better you send it as big-data="vm.data"

Comment: `{{}}` will convert all data to string format, rather use `bindings: {bigData: '<'}` sign inside `component` which will help you to pass json object as is, and then use `big-data="vm.data"`

Comment: @PankajParkar - at present i am using `@` as an input param along with `{{vm.data}}`. Is it fine or that needs to be changed. I dont see any difference with stringified json or straight away using it with expression tag. And i parse as json object when retrieving it. But my question is which is best, either by an custom defined service or as an input to component?

Comment: @Mithun its better use &

Comment: change `@` to `<`, It doesn't make sense to me to do manual conversion and pass value into attribute of an element. I'd say passing data via bindings is good in this case..

Comment: @PankajParkar - It throws error when i try to bind for `<` as: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{vm.data}}] starting at [{vm.data}}].`

Comment: @Mithun after changing binding to `<` you should use `big-data="vm.data"` instead of `big-data="{{vm.data}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are passing your data through a simple attribute to the component or through `@`.

In my opinion you should define `big-data` as binding parameter through `<`, which allows you to pass angular expressions and then pass the data to the component. It has been introduced exactly in order to avoid the `@` when you want to avoid objects conversions.

About passing data in general to the component, if your component manipulates that data, sure you can pass it directly all the data as a binding parameter. 
There are actually no restrictions about that.

Then if it's better to use a shared service between the component and the app in order to get the data, this is usually depending on the specific use case.

For example, if your component works always with the same type of data, retrieved by always the same request, maybe you can get the data directly inside the component through an embedded service.

But actually the goal of components is to have a reusable code, so usually the approach you are having is a good choice, because your component could be reused providing any kind of data.

Actually the data is out-of-the-box and it's working doesn't depend on the particular data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination @quirimmo. I get error when i try to bind using `<` . `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{vm.data}}] starting at [{vm.data}}]`.

Comment: If big-data is a @ parameter, try removing the interpolation {{}}

Comment: Awesome fantastic @quirimmo, it worked like a charm. One last question to add here, what if the data gets changed inside need to update outside the component. How do i do that? vm.data which is being passed will change internally by edit and remove operations. How to update it in parent scope? Ill accept your answer right away, but plz help me understand this w.r.to angular 1.5

Comment: Sure no problem. In these cases a two way data binding through the `=` parameter is the best way. 
This means that every time you will change big-data inside the component, the parameter will change also outside. 
If you change the parameter outside, it will change also automatically inside the component.
There are also few other ways to achieve the same, like using callbacks parameters `&`, sending messages through `$emit` or `$broadcast``but in this specific case what you need is simply to define the parameter as `=`.
I hope this helps

Comment: I know about $emit and $broadcast but need to get rid off $scope usage. Do i need to do any other manipulation in 2 way binding? `vm.data = this.data;`. Is it sufficient to handle in the receiver side. And i do `delete vm.data[0]`. Will it affects straight away from the caller component?

Comment: yeah sure try to avoid messages every time you can. Your case is absolutely a two way data binding through `=`.
Nope that's all you need. And yes it will affect also the other. Actually you have to think that they refer to the same variable so manipulating one it's like manipulating the other one.

Comment: `<test-component big-data="vm.data"></test-component>`. And in the receiving side. `vm.data = this.bigData`. Is it fine in this case?

Comment: remove again the interpolation. Usually you don't need interpolation in all the angularjs stuffs. Interpolation is implicit.
From outside the component you have to do just: `vm.data = myNewData;` 
From inside the component you have to use `bigData` instead.
Does it make sense?

Comment: Forgot to remove, Is it fine with that case?

Comment: sorry I pressed enter before to finish to write I was looking for a break line only :D I think if you read again the comment now it should be complete